# (LSTM with R) How Backtested cross validation RMSE can used for the actual LSTM forecasting model

Tags: r, cross-validation, lstm, rms

This blog was super helpful to build LSTM code in R

https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/04/time-series-deep-learning-forecasting-sunspots-with-keras-stateful-lstm-in-r/

So, I tried to use RMSE that is calculated from the backtested cross-validation to RMSE for forecasting future value. **Then I have a question that how do we know the LSTM model applied to Backtestd cross-validation is the same model that used to predict future value?** In other word, how do we know that the model created for Backtested in '5.2.1 Creating An LSTM Prediction Function' is the same model applied to '5.3 Predicting The Next 10 Years'? I can see the functions (predict_keras_lstm_future() and lstm_prediction()) are pretty much same, but that doesn't mean that they are the same modeling.

**How can I connect the backtesting result to actual forecasting?**

Comment: You mean if the model changes parameter (estimate) values between the two functions?

Comment: @Dave   Maybe, if parameter values change, then are they  different model? then if parameters stay same then, can we say they are same model?

Comment: If you have all the same parameters in the same architecture, then they're the same model. If you change a parameter, then it is a different model. (Be careful about the context in how "model" is used, as sometimes that is used to indicate the type of model e.g. LSTM.)

Comment: @Dave then how do you call it in NN instead of a model? Thank you so much

Comment: I don't follow what you're asking, but I think the answer is that it's because you're using a neural network.